# "Broken" unicode strings encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: python, django, unicode, utf-8

I have been studying unicode and its Python implementation now for two days, and I think I'm getting a glimpse of what it is about. Just to get confident, I'm asking if my assumptions for my current problems are correct.

In Django, forms give me unicode strings which I suspect to be "broken". Unicode strings in Python should be encoded in UTF-8, is that right? After entering the string "fähre" into a text field, the browser sends the string "f%c3%a4hre" in the POST request (checked via wireshark). When I retrieve the value via form.cleaned_data, I'm getting the string u'f\xa4hre' (note it is a unicode string), though. As far as I understand that, that is ISO-8859-1-encoded unicode string, which is incorrect. The correct string should be u'f\xc3\xa4hre', which would be a UTF-8-encoded unicode string. Is that a Django bug or is there something wrong with my understanding of it?
To fix the issue, I wrote a function to apply it to any text input from Django forms:

```
def fix_broken_unicode(s):
    return unicode(s.encode(u'utf-8'), u'iso-8859-1')
```

which does

```
>>> fix_broken_unicode(u'f\xa4hre')
u'f\xc3\xa4hre'
```

That doesn't seem very elegant to me, but setting Django's settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET to 'utf-8' didn't help, nor did anything else. I am trying to work with unicode throughout the whole application so I won't get any weird errors later on, but it obviously does not suffice to mark all strings with u'...'.

**Edit:** Considering the answers from Dirk and sth, I will now save the strings to the database as they are. The real problem was that I was trying to urlencode these kinds of strings to use them as input for the Twitter API etc. In GET or POST requests, though, UTF-8 encoding is obviously expected which the standard urllib.urlencode() function does not process correctly (throws exceptions). Take a look at my solution in the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4LmKKTe0) and feel free to comment on it also.

Comment: you cannot save the unicode strings "to the database as they are," because (as sth explained), unicode strings are not really encoded as anything, and you need to encode them in order to store them in the db.

Comment: also, urllib.urlencode() is probably more correct than you. why don't you show us what you are trying to do and what the actual exception is?

Comment: @hop I cannot give the whole example because it is rather complex and spread over a bunch of classes. Also the HTTP request I am using the data for requires a paid account for the Twingly API, a social media search index, so I cannot provide a working URL here. I am going to try to make up an equivalent example on coming weekend.

Comment: and so you should. in reducing your code to the necessary minimum for showing the problem, you will probably solve it by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`u'f\xa4hre'`is a unicode string, not encoded as anything. The unicode codepoint `0xa4` is the character `ä`. It is not really important that `ä` would also be encoded as byte `0xa4` in ISO-8859-1.

The unicode string can contain any unicode characters without encoding them in some way. For example `轮渡` would be represented as `u'\u8f6e\u6e21'`, which are simply two unicode codepoints. The UTF-8 encoding would be the much longer `'\xe8\xbd\xae\xe6\xb8\xa1'`.

So there is no need to fix the encoding, you are just seeing the internal representation of the unicode string.

Comment: What if a module returns things like `u'\xe8\xbd\xae\xe6\xb8\xa1'`?  Isn't that incorrect?

Comment: @endolith: It isn't strictly invalid, but it's nonsense (`u'è½®æ¸¡'`), obviously not the intended `u'轮渡'`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly: after having been decoded, the unicode string is *unicode* which means, it may contain characters with codes beyond 255. How the interpreter represents these depends on the platform, but usually nowadays it uses character elements with a width of at least 16 bits. ISO-8859-1 is a proper subset of unicode. Thus, the string `u'f\xa4hre'` is actually proper -- the `\xa4`  is a rendering artifact, since Python doesn't know if (and when) it is safe to include characters with codes beyond a certain range on the console.

UTF-8 is a *transport encoding* that is, a special way to write unicode data such, that it can be stored in "channels" with an element width of 8 bits per character/byte. In order to compute the proper "external" (or transport) encoding of a unicode string, you'd use the `encode` method, passing the desired representation. It returns a properly encoded *byte string* (as opposed to a unicode character string).

The reverse transformation is `decode` which takes a *byte string* and an encoding name and yields a unicode *character string*.

Comment: One note to this "after having been decoded, the unicode string is unicode which means, it may contain characters with codes beyond 255.". A unicode character has a code point and name, no number. The unicode character is a highlevel object thing. If you serialize this object, then you have to give the character a number.